# Unable to add a datanode to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I got all my settings right and I am able to run `Hadoop ( 1.1.2 )` on a single-Node. However, after making the changes to the relevant files ( /etc/hosts, *-site.xml ), I am not able to add a **Datanode** to the cluster and I keep getting the following error on the Slave.

Anybody knows how to rectify this?

```
2013-05-13 15:36:10,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-05-13 15:36:11,137 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-05-13 15:36:12,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `fs.default.name` in your core-site.xml conf file (on each node in your cluster). This needs to be the network name of the name node and i suspect you have this as `hdfs://localhost:54310`).

Failing that check for any mention of localhost in your hadoop configuration files on all nodes in your cluster:

```
grep localhost $HADOOP_HOME/conf/*.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

try relpacing localhost with the namenode's ip address or network name